# preprocessor function and object like macros

Tags: c-preprocessor

```
#define NAME RAGHU
#define NAIVE_STR(x) #x
int main()
{
printf("%s", NAIVE_STR(NAME)); 
getch();
return 0;
}
```

how can we modify the code so that whatever we had defined in NAME get printed?

Comment: Is there a reason for not using `#define NAME "RAGHU"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```
#define NAME RAGHU
#define NAIVE_STR(x) #x
#define DEF_TO_STRING(x) NAIVE_STR(x)
int main()
{
    printf("%s", DEF_TO_STRING(NAME)); 
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

This is how defines work. When you call `NAIVE_STR(NAME)` pre-processor sees `#x` and doesn't substitute `x` with it's value so string `NAME`  is returned. But when you call `DEF_TO_STRING(NAME)` it doesn't see `#` and substitutes `NAME` with `RAGHU` and then calls `NAIVE_STR(RAGHU)` and  `NAIVE_STR(RAGHU)` just returns `RAGHU`

Comment: +1. Clever way to do it without modifying the existing #defines

Comment: @parrowdice May you suggest one?

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar I don't think there are any other options because it is the way suggested by compiler developers http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html